# SwiftUI Button set background black without white border

Tags: button, swiftui, swiftui-clipshape

I am trying to create a swiftui button that is all black background with white text but when I am getting a whitish/greyish border with this code:

```
                Button(action: {
                    viewStore.send(.googleSSOButtonTapped)
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("google")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                        Text("Sign in with Google")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(8.0)
                    .shadow(radius: 4.0)
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
                }
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem. When the button is shown in isolation there is no surrounding blank area. So what container do you have around the button?